# How to open login form in popup window, then close it when form submitted and reload previous page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, authentication

I have a webmap application with a login button that opens a login form.

**`index.php` holds the map with the loggin button:**

```
<img src="app/images/login.png" height="50px" width="130px" align="right" onclick="javascript:openLogin()">

function openLogin(){
            var p1 = 'scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no'
            var p2 = 'width=300,height=300,left=-500,top=-500'
            open('login.html', 'login', p1+p2);
        }
```

**`login.html` hold the login form**

Simple login form with username + password and submit button that redirects to a `checklogin.php` page and then if the username and password are good, redirects to the webmap page `index.php`.

**What it actually does:**

The popup opens, the login form works but then the web map page is opened in the popup window.

**What I want:**

I want the popup to close after the login form is submitted, and instead of having the new `index.php` page load in the popup, it loads in the page where the login button was clicked.

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks !